# Неправильная кодировка в opera, firefox локально на Денвере

Tags: кодировка, utf-8

Неправильная кодировка в opera, firefox локально на Денвере.

> Пользуюсь notepad++ стоит кодировка
> "Кодировать в UTF-8 без BOM"

**Нормально отображается** в safari, IE, chrome, и если просто открыть файл в .. opera, firefox.

**Плохо отображается** в opera и firefox когда запускаю с локального сервера "Денвер"

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: А какая кодировка у денвера стоит по умолчанию для ответов?

Comment: Подскажи как глянуть!?

Comment: Наверное где-то в настройках апача лежать должно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел,убрал ansi 
httpd.conf файл находиться в usr -> local -> apache -> conf

Answer (score 0):

Прописать через файл .htaccess, например так

AddDefaultCharset Utf-8